# Automatic position with sorting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a table that can sort through messages and when they were sent. Right now when the user enters the page it starts with ordering the message body, I'd like it to start with the sent at time desc when a user starts the page. I'll show some code and a screenshot. I also found this code on railscast #228.

Here are the methods that sort them.

```
 def sort_column
  Message.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "body"
 end

 def sort_direction
  %w(asc desc).include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
 end
```

Here is the view

```
 <tbody>
    <% @message.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= message.body %></td>
        <td><%= time_ago_in_words message.created_at %> ago</td>
        <td><%= message.groups.order(:id).pluck(:name).to_sentence %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

This what the user sees when they open the page, as you can see the arrow is on messages. I'd like the arrow to be at "send at" with the direction desc.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is enough info but let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sort_column` and `sort_direction` functions default to `"body"` and `"asc"`.

If you want to default the sort order to default to `created_at`, change the functions like so:

```
def sort_column
  Message.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at"
end

def sort_direction
  %w(asc desc).include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
end
```

Comment: You're right but I have these methods for two different tables. So if I do that for one it will wrongly format my other view. any suggestions?

Comment: There are any number of options of things that you could do at this point.  A simple place to start would be to edit your `sort_column` method to use a class variable like

    `Message.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : @default_sort_column || "created_at"`

And then in the actions, set the `@default_sort_column` variable

Comment: I'm a bit new to ruby could you edit your answer with that comment to make it clearer for me?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display messages by creation date, pull 'em in the index action like this:

```
Message.order(created_at: :desc)
```